# write_sheet() error: Don't know how to make an instance of `CellData` from something of class 'data.frame'

Tags: r, mongodb-query, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

I queried this from our mongoDB

```
data2 <- table$find(
  query = '{"disabled" : true}',
  fields = '{"general.name" : true, "_id": true')
```

`View(data)` looks as I would expect it but when I try to use the `googlesheets4::write_sheet(data = data2, ss = "a google url", sheet = "a name")`

it gives out this message:

```
Writing to "gsheetname"
Writing to sheet "a name"
Error: Don't know how to make an instance of `CellData` from something of class 'data.frame'.
```

creating an xls or csv works fine but gsheet doesn't. Data frames from other sources than mongoDB, can be written into a gsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to answer without sample data.

However, I have encountered this error and the problem is that the data frame contains a column with nested data. Using the tidyr, I have found `unnest()` to flatten the columns will allow the sheet to be written.

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html#grouped-data-frames